# Android Studio fails downloading SDK Components

Tags: android, 15.04, development

I installed android studio using ubuntu-make like

```
umake android
```

after starting android studio, it asks some questions and then starts downloading SDK components, but it never finishes that successfully. I tried that using ubuntu 14.10 already and had the same problems there. Now, with ubuntu 15.04 things haven't changed, I got my homedirectory completly new on the install, so I doubt there is anything from an old installation.

The install of SDK compoments fails with the following output:

```
Refresh Sources:
  Failed to fetch URL http://dl.google.com/android/repository/addons_list-2.xml, reason: File not found
  Fetched Add-ons List successfully
  Refresh Sources
  Failed to fetch URL http://dl.google.com/android/repository/repository-10.xml, reason: File not found
Refresh Sources:
  Failed to fetch URL http://dl.google.com/android/repository/repository-10.xml, reason: File not found
There is nothing to install or update.
The following SDK components were not installed: platform-tools, extra-android-m2repository and extra-google-m2repository
```

So, how can I get android studio to work?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't use the shell to install Android Studio, but I had a similar error message, when starting Android Studio and it wanted to update it.
What I did, was going to /opt/ and using `chmod -R 777` on all the android directories.